# QList filled in constructor but accessed in other function

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I'm not very sure about this C++ code.

```
#include <QList>
#include <QString>

using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    public:
            QList<QString> m_List;

    MyClass() {
            QString text1("foo1");
            m_List << text1;

            QString text2("foo2");
            m_List << text2;
    }

};

int main() {
    MyClass myClass;
    for (int i = 0; i < myClass.m_List.size(); ++i) {
            cout << myClass.m_List.at(i).toStdString()  << endl;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it's work because I create and add **QString** in my **QList** in the constructor.
So, my instance **text1** shouldn't exist anymore at the end of constructor and when I access to **QList** element in the loop this shouldn't work, but the output look nice :

```
foo1
foo2
```

**cppcheck** don't say anything about this code.
This code is it correct ?

Comment: Your code is correct, once you add a string to the list, the string is copied to the list, meaning that text1 and text2 can leave scope and be destroyed and the list wouldn't be affected.

Comment: Jamey D formulates it very well. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Strings are simply values. They got copied into the list. This is no different than if you used `std::string`. Things would be nearly useless if the code you show didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.

Yes, the local instances do not exist anymore. But that does not matter. QList stores data by value. What ever you pass to a QList is copied and the copy is stored in the list. So even if your local QString objects where discarded when leaving the constructor, the copies in QList still exist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for a QString it stores the value in the array

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlist.html#details

> Internally, QList is represented as an array of pointers to items
>   of type T. If T is itself a pointer type or a basic type that is no
>   larger than a pointer, or if T is one of Qt's shared classes, then
>   QList stores the items directly in the pointer array.

Also take a look at: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html#list-of-classes